# Virtuemart 2.0 attach media to product

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

A simple question

I have a Joomla 2.5 with VirtueMart 2.0 installed.

This website has been upgraded from Joomla 1.5, and my migration process was done "manually" (database scripts which filled the new Virtuemart tables from old ones)

I am unable to add a media file to a product, which is supposed to be a very simple function

I go to the media file manager for the product and click the "New" link

The media file is uploaded & created, but it is not linked to the product

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VM2.0 or above Then you can find a table name with `#__virtuemart_product_medias` In this table VM keeping product id and media id.
 You will get all the images that assigned with a product from this table.
Also from the product details tab in admin you can choose multiple images for a single product.

If you are upgraded keep a new version separate and compare and update to your upgrading site.

Hope it will helps..

Comment: Thanks, but what I need to do is add a new media file for a product in the admin (product details tab), but it doesn't work. I go to "product images" and there is no such option. There is only a "New" button which adds a file but the file is not being attached to the product. Thanks